# Image is not being displayed on the ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have created a dynamic image which is being saved in the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method. 
 I load image like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <p>
       &nbsp;</p>
    <img alt="aa" class="style1" longdesc="aa"
        src="file:///C:/project/Image/hours.png" />
</asp:Content>
```

But only thing which is being displayed is:
[image]

I knew it's kind of stupid question but I can't make it work.. Can any one point me where I am doing mistake?

Comment: try something like `~/Image/hours.png` google `Relative Path and Absolute Path`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot interact with the file system on the client.

You need to reference an image on the server using a relative or absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a relative or absolute path on the server. something that would look like "~/../Image/hours.png".